# How to add an image to a column based on the value of another column (and have it show correctly in Gallery view)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

**Desired Behavior**:

1. Display an image in the column `My Image` based on the value in the column `Model`.

   `My Image` is type `Picture` (I also tried making it type `Image` but got the same outcome).

   `Model` is type `Managed Metadata`.
2. When clicking on the image, open the image in a new tab.
3. In `Gallery` view, when list entries are displayed as cards, the image is visible on the card.

**Actual Behavior**

Desired behavior `1` and `2` is working, `3` is not.

[image]

**What I've Tried**:

Below are various stages of applying column formatting to the `My Image` column.

GOOD:  This displays the managed metadata column value:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "[$Model]"
}
```

GOOD:  This displays the image path as text, based on the value in the `Model` column:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=if([$Model] =='Computer Model 1', 'https://my-tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/my-site/Asset%20Images/computer_model_1.png', 'no')"
}
```

GOOD:  This display the image, based on the value in the `Model` column:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "img",
  "attributes": {
  "src": "=if([$Model] =='Computer Model 1', 'https://my-tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/my-site/Asset%20Images/computer_model_1.png', 'no')"
  }
}
```

GOOD:  This makes the image a link and adds some styling:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "attributes": {
    "href": "=if([$Model] =='Computer Model 1', 'https://my-tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/my-site/Asset%20Images/computer_model_1.png', 'no')",
    "target": "_blank"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "img",
      "style": {
        "padding": "0",
        "width": "100px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "src": "=if([$Model] =='Computer Model 1', 'https://my-tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/my-site/Asset%20Images/computer_model_1.png', 'no')"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

All of these things are working.

BAD:  The only thing that is not working is that the image is not displaying in `Gallery` view.

For troubleshooting, below is a comparison of the HTML and CSS of the image section in the card:

*Normal Picture*:

```
<div class="sp-card-previewColumnContainer">
    <div class="sp-card-imageContainer">
        <div class="ms-bgColor-neutralLight sp-card-imagePreviewBackground">
            <img style="display:;" src="https://my-tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/my-site/SiteAssets/Lists/letters-and-numbers/computer_model_1.png" title="computer_model_1.png" class="sp-card-imagePreview">
                <svg style="display:none;" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 210 105" class="sp-card-defaultImage ms-bgColor-themeLighter" focusable="false">...</path>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*Dynamically Added Picture*:

```
<div class="sp-card-previewColumnContainer">
    <div class="sp-card-imageContainer">
        <div class="ms-bgColor-neutralLight sp-card-imagePreviewBackground">
            <img style="display:none;" src="" title="" class="sp-card-imagePreview">
                <svg style="display:;" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 210 105" class="sp-card-defaultImage ms-bgColor-themeLighter">...</svg>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*Related Reading:*

[Populate Column with IMAGE based on another column's content](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/276469/populate-column-with-image-based-on-another-columns-content)

[In a Sharepoint List: Display an Image (field type “Hyperlink or Picture”)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/255389/in-a-sharepoint-list-display-an-image-field-type-hyperlink-or-picture)

[Apply conditional formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#apply-conditional-formatting)

[Add conditional images in a column (SharePoint Online list)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/377332/add-conditional-images-in-a-column-sharepoint-onli.html)

**Update**

For reference, after first answer, I tried the following:

I searched for `sp-card-previewColumnContainer` and looked for the next `elmType` of `img` and could see it had a `style` > `display` of `=if([$Image] == '', 'none', '')`, so I removed that `style` object, and then I could see `"src": "[$Image]", "title": "[$Image.desc]", "class": "sp-card-imagePreview"` so I replaced the `src` value with the `if` conditional I used in the column formatting, and just changed the description to `hello world`.  the next two `svg` objects also had the `display:none` styling so I removed those objects as well.  The result was good, except there was a little icon in the middle of each card.  I put back those `style` objects on the last two `svg's`, but it still displayed the same:

[image]

In the JSON above, `[$Image]` is my `Picture` column.

**Update 2**

I removed the `children` array that contained the following, and it seems to have worked, ie got rid of those little icons.

```
sp-card-defaultImageOverlay-path1

sp-card-defaultImageOverlay-path2

sp-card-defaultImageOverlay-path3

sp-card-defaultImageOverlay-path4
```

Comment: Can you show us the JSON code of gallery view?

Comment: I am just clicking on `Switch view options` icon and selecting `Gallery`.  So there are no customisations to that.  Am looking at the list ending in `/AllItems.aspx?env=WebViewList` - just appending that `?env=WebViewList` to the URL automatically gives the list the full width styling etc.

Comment: When you change to the gallery view, there is auto-generated JSON by SharePoint. You have to customize the auto-generated JSON to implement the logic to show the image dynamically (same as you did in column formatting).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are showing the image dynamically using JSON in column formatting, it is working fine in list view.

But, JSON formatting only displays the value/image in list view >> It does not store the actual value in list columns.

So, to show the image in **Gallery** view, you have to replicate the same logic (used in column formatting) in auto-generated JSON code of gallery view.

To open the JSON code of gallery view, follow below steps:

1. Go to your SharePoint list
2. Click on **switch view options** dropdown at the top & select **Format current view**.

   [image]
3. Make sure **Format view** & **Gallery** is selected like below:

   [image]
4. Click on **Edit card** & then select **Advanced mode**

---

**Additional reference**:

1. [Change the width of a card in Gallery view of a List](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/293460/change-the-width-of-a-card-in-gallery-view-of-a-list/293464#293464)

Comment: Getting closer, have added description of what I did and the results to end of original question, just need to remove those little icons somehow...i am going to try and hide everything that creates svg with the class `sp-card-defaultImageOverlay`.

Comment: For `display` property of `svg` elements, you need opposite conditions of `img` element. that means, when there is no image, default svg icons will be shown.

Comment: Have added another update, with steps that seem to have got desired behaviour.  I wonder what happens when Microsoft pushes out an update though, will that Gallery Layout JSON get overridden?

Comment: If you don't want the default svg icons when there is no image, you can completely remove the `svg` elements as well.

Comment: No, customized JSON will not get overridden by any update from Microsoft.

Comment: Interestingly, after making those changes I have documented in original question, when I click on the `Switch view options` icon at the top right of the list, it no longer has an option of `Gallery`, it says `Tiles` instead :(.